# How to setup MS Exchange Server 2010 after changing IIS port?

Tags: exchange-2010, port, iis-7.5

The problem is we have Apache running on the same machine and Apache is our prime HTTP server (I like it, kill me ;-)). Anyway we managed to change IIS port but then OWA and MS Exchange Console stopped working. Don't really understand why, especially because OWA was working through https and we didn't change SSL port for IIS.

I'm just hoping there is a way out of this...

Answer (score 2):

You're going to create Exchange headaches trying to mess with the HTTP bindings for Exchange services.

If I were you I'd either move Apache to its not on the Exchange server, or if you've got no choice but to leave it there then add another interface/IP and bind Apache to that other IP so they each have their own IP's and can listen on the same ports without conflict.

Comment: I guess we could do something like that, but that wouldn't solve problems with accessing our site internally. I guess it is possible to work around it, but would it really be that hard to change the port? Is port 80 just hardcoded as in some $10 application? Sorry I'm just refusing to believe Microsoft done something like that.

Comment: you can have multiple internal IPs as well on your nic, you can then create a dns record in your internal dns servers too so it goes to the right ip when requested.

Normally Exchange servers are installed on dedicated boxes and websites (if being hosted) are done by IIS - but if you bind multiple IP Addresses to your machine internally - that should resolve your problem even when accessing the site internally - Paul is right !! :-)

Answer (score 0):

http://briandesmond.com/blog/redirecting-owa-urls-in-exchange-2010/
can you not create a redirect rule in your apache config to redirect any requests for exchange to IIS on that port / url ? you can get some idea from the link above.

Comment: Mhm... No. I need Apache to be accessible via 80 from outside and inside of our network. I have mod_rewrite running and I don't want get into trouble. What I want to do is run a following dialogue ;-) - Hey Exchange, IIS is running on port 81 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS. - OK, reconfiguring (says Exchange).